# Are detailed questions about medical billing and health insurance considered on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, questions

Medical billing and Health insurance (at least in the US) are quite complicated. From my experience, there are also lots of errors made by billing departments and insurance companies, and almost never in the patients favor.

Are nuanced questions about this process on topic? For example:

> My insurance company sent me an EOB with a "Billed amount" of $290, an allowed amount of $0, and a deductible of $350? I later got a bill from the (in-network) provider for $350. Is it normal and legal for an insurance company to adjust the amount I owe over the amount the provider originally billed?

These kinds of issues aren't rare, and possible mistakes in bills can certainly have a bearing on ones finances, but perhaps this topic is too narrow.

Answer (score 5):

I see quite a lot of questions that go into a lot of details on billing, so I think this one is fine. https://money.stackexchange.com/search?q=EOB has some existing examples.